# How to navigate in eclipse from method implementation to method definition in interface?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm looking for eclipse function to navigate from method implementation to method definition in interface. 
Inverses of "Quick Type Hierarchy" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: I think F3 doesnt remember

Comment: Pressing `Ctrl+T` for the second time will show you the supertype hierarchy, eclipse is helpful and tells you it will do it after you pressed it the first time so I don't know how you missed it, maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Oleg: super! make it as answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for the first time you will see the following:

[image]

As you can see in the red "circle" eclipse is being helpful and suggests to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> again to see the supertype hierarchy which will give you what you want:

[image]